# NSURLConnection with NSRunLoopCommonModes

Tags: objective-c, ios, concurrency, nsurlconnection, nsrunloop

I have written my own implementation of HTTPClient for my iOS app to download contents of specified URL asynchronously. The HTTPClient uses NSOperationQueue to enqueue the NSURLConnection requests. I chose NSOperationQueue because I wanted to cancel any or all on-going NSURLConnection at any point of time.

I did a good amount of research on how to implement my HTTPClient and I had two choices for executing NSURLConnection:

1) Execute each enqueued NSURLConnection on a separate secondary thread. NSOperationQueue executes each enqueued operation on a secondary thread in background and hence I didn't need to do anything explicitly to spawn secondary threads except starting my NSURLConnection in overridden start method of NSOperation subclass and running the runloop for the spawned secondary thread until either connectionDidFinishLoading or connectionDidFailWithError is called. It looks like below:

```
if (self.connection != nil) {
            do {
                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                         beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
            } while (!self.isFinished);
}
```

2) Execute each enqueued NSURLConnection on the main thread. For this inside the start method, I was using performSelectorOnMainThread and calling start method again on main thread. With this approach I was scheduling the NSURLConnection with NSRunLoopCommonModes as below:

```
[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

I chose this second approach and implemented it. From my research, this second approach seemed better because it doesn't start a separate secondary thread for each NSURLConnection. Now at any point of time, in the application there could be many requests going on simultaneously and with the first approach, this means the same number of secondary threads will be spawned and will not return to the pool until the associated url requests finish.

I was under the impression that I am still running concurrently with the second approach by scheduling the NSURLConnection with the NSRunLoopCommonModes. In other terms with this approach I thought that I am using NSRunLoopCommonModes instead of multi-threading for concurrency so that the observers for NSURLConnection will call either connectionDidFinishLaunching or connectionDidFailWithError as soon as it can irrespective of what main thread is doing with UI at that point of time.

Unfortunately all my understanding proved wrong when this morning one of my colleagues showed me that with the current implementation, the NSURLConnection doesn't return until a scroll view on one of the view controllers stops scrolling. The NSURLRequest to get data is started when the scroll view is about to stop scrolling but even though it was completed before the scroll view stops calling, somehow the NSURLConnection doesn't calls back either connectionDidFinishLoading or connectionDidFailWithError until the scroll view stops scrolling completely. This means that the whole idea of scheduling NSURLConnection with NSRunLoopCommonModes on main thread to get real concurrency with UI operations (touches/scroll) proved wrong and the NSURLConnection still waits till the main thread is busy scrolling the scroll view.

I tried switching to first approach of using secondary threads and it works like a charm. The NSURLConnection still calls one of its protocol methods while the scroll view is still scrolling. This is clear because now NSURLConnection is not running on main thread so it would not wait for the scroll view to stop scrolling.

I really don't want to use first approach because it's expensive due to multi threading.

Could someone please let me know if my understanding about the second approach is not correct? If it is correct, what could be the reason for scheduling NSURLConnection with NSRunLoopCommonModes doesn't work as expected?

I would highly appreciate if the answer is little more descriptive because it is supposed to clear lot more doubts for me regarding how exactly the NSRunLoop and NSRunLoopModes work. Just to specify I have read the documentation for this many times already.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was simpler than I imagined.

I was having this in the start method of NSOperation subclass

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.urlRequest
                                                              delegate:self];

[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Now the problem is the above initWithRequest:delegate: method actually schedules the NSURLConnection in default runloop with NSDefaultRunLoopMode and completely ignores the next line where I actually try to schedule it with NSRunLoopCommonModes. By changing above two lines with below worked as expected.

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.urlRequest
                                                              delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

[self.connection start];
```

The actual problem here was I must initialize the NSURLConnection using the constructor method with the parameter startImmediately. When I pass NO for the parameter startImmediately, the connection is not scheduled with the default run loop. It can be scheduled in the run loop and mode of choice by calling scheduleInRunLoop:forMode: method.

Now the NSURLConnection initiated from the method scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset is calling its delegate methods connectionDidFinishLoading/connectionDidFailWithError while the scroll view is still scrolling and has not yet finished scrolling.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: That's strange. I would think that scheduling the connection for `NSRunLoopCommonModes` after init'ing would schedule it in *additional* modes on top of the default mode. Sounds like a framework bug to me if that didn't happen. Given that it didn't, that explains the issue: `NSRunLoopCommonModes` contains `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` among others, and that's presumably what's used while scrolling is being processed.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling a run loop source doesn't allow the source's callbacks to run concurrently with other source's callbacks.

In the case of a network communication, things which the kernel handles, like receiving and buffering packets, happens concurrently regardless of what your app does.  Then, the kernel marks a socket as readable or writable which may, for example, wake a `select()` or `kevent()` call -- if the thread was blocked in such a call.  If your thread was doing something else, like handling scroll events, then it won't notice the socket's readability/writability until execution returns to the run loop.  Only then will `NSURLConnection`'s run loop source call its callback, letting NSURLConnection process the socket state change, and possibly call your delegate methods.

Next is the question of what happens when a run loop has multiple sources and more than one is ready.  For example, there are more scroll events in the event queue and also your socket is readable or writable. Ideally, you might like a fair algorithm to service run loop sources.  In reality, it's possible that GUI events are prioritized over other run loop sources.  Also, run loop sources can have an inherent priority ("order") relative to other sources.

Usually, it is not critical that, say, an `NSURLConnection` be serviced instantly.  It's usually OK to allow it to wait for the main thread's run loop to get around to it. Consider that, for the same reason that `NSURLConnection`'s run loop source won't be serviced while scrolling, there's no way that processing it on a background thread could have a user-visible effect. For example, how would it affect the UI of your app? It would use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:..` or something like that to schedule the update. But that is just as likely to be starved as the `NSURLConnection` run loop source.

However, if you absolutely can't abide this possible delay, there's a middle ground between scheduling your `NSURLConnection`s on the main thread or scheduling them all on separate threads. You can schedule all of them on the same thread but not the main thread. You can create a single thread that you park in its run loop. Then, where you are currently doing `-performSelectorOnMainThread:...`, you could instead do `-performSelector:onThread:...`.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your detailed explanation. However I don't agree with "Scheduling a run loop source doesn't allow the source's callbacks to run concurrently with other source's callbacks."
If you schedule a run loop source with NSRunLoopCommonModes then the callbacks for that source can run concurrently with other sources. This is why NSRunLoopCommonModes exists in my opinion. From the documentation, "Common modes are a set of run loop modes for which you can define a set of sources, timers, and observers that are shared by these modes."

Comment: Two things: 1) the sources' *callbacks* can't run concurrently. There is no magic to run loops. A single thread can only be doing one thing at a time. How a given source is implemented is unknown to us. Some may use a secondary thread internally. Others may only provide the sort of concurrency I mentioned where network communications are handled by the kernel. But that doesn't change the fact about callbacks. 2) You misunderstand `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. It's just a shorthand for saying "schedule my source in a bunch of modes". At any time a run loop is still only running one of those modes.

Comment: Ken, I quoted your statement while saying callbacks run concurrently. Probably when you mention network communication, asynchronous is the appropriate word than concurrency. Also NSRunLoopCommonModes indicates that when you schedule a source in this mode, it will be processed by the run loop no matter in which mode the run loop is running. In my example, when the scroll view was scrolling the run loop was in NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode but since earlier I failed to schedule NSURLConnection with NSRunLoopCommonModes I didn't get the update until run loop mode became NSDefaultRunLoopMode

Comment: 1) You quoted my statement but disagreed. I reiterate that it's correct. I don't know what you're saying this time. 2) Network comm. is *both* asynchronous and concurrent. The kernel is doing stuff like buffering and ACKing, etc., while your app does other things. 3) `NSRunLoopCommonModes` definitely does **not** mean "it will be processed ... no matter in which mode the run loop is running". Certain modes are in the set of common modes, all others are not. The frameworks add some modes to the set. You can add others using `CFRunLoopAddCommonMode()`.

Answer (score 0):

My testing is successful for "scheduleInRunLoop:(NSRunLoop *)aRunLoop forMode:(NSString *)mode" on a second thread, also it can scheduleInRunLoop back to the main run loop from the second thread.

Partial code like below:

```
NSRunLoop *runloop; //global

self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:runloop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

[self.connection start];
```

If you want to run NSURLConnection in another thread, you should create a run loop like this in your thread's main method (the thread should launch before above code starts):

```
runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

while (!finished)
{
   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
}
```

Official documents are very userful:

> By default, a connection is scheduled on the current thread in the
>   default mode when it is created. If you create a connection with the
>   initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO for
>   the startImmediately parameter, you can schedule the connection on a
>   different run loop or mode before starting it with the start method.
>   You can schedule a connection on multiple run loops and modes, or on
>   the same run loop in multiple modes. You cannot reschedule a
>   connection after it has started.

Comment: The use of [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1] in a while loop like that can lead to memory being retained on the heap. If this approach is used, I recommend it be combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208759/why-doesnt-arc-free-memory-when-using-nsdate-date-but-works-fine-using-nsda

Answer (score 0):

Using the guidance from Ken Thomases' answer I have produced this for the copy paste type of coders:

```
static NSThread *connectionProcessingThread;
static NSTimer *keepRunloopBusy;
static NSRunLoop *oauth2runLoop;

+ (void)initialize
{
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    connectionProcessingThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithBlock:^{
        oauth2runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        keepRunloopBusy = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:DBL_MAX repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer* timer) {
            NSLog(@"runloop is kept busy with this keepalive work");
        }];
        [oauth2runLoop addTimer:keepRunloopBusy forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [oauth2runLoop run];
    }];
    [connectionProcessingThread start];
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
});
}
```

and then you'd fork

```
NSURLConnection *aConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:startRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];    // don't start yet
if( [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] != [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]) {
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
    [aConnection scheduleInRunLoop:oauth2runLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
} else {
    [aConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; // let's first schedule it in the main runloop.
}
[aConnection start];    // now start
```